# Android TableView breaking constraints due to content

Tags: android, layout, tableview

I've set up a relatively simple tableview for left label/right detail data:
[image: Android studio view of table]

My textboxes are not set to have single line or any funny business, (the top one pictured is missing some padding applied to all the rest) but when rendered since the content is long my table is getting pushed off the screen:

[image: table]

How can I tell my table not to grow past the size of the screen?

Comment: use fixed width

Comment: While that would work, it's not really a good strategy when dealing with multiple devices at different resolutions/screen sizes, no?

Comment: yes.absolutely not recommended.but that will helpful in your requirement.i think you are not taken weight of text view..please take the weight as 1..it will adjust the exceeded text automatically.